# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Picasso-refQueue"

Tags: android, azure-pipelines

I'm facing the below issue in the Azure pipeline while executing unit tests and generating code coverage reports for an Android app. The pipeline is failing with the below error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-12"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-23"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-3"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-2"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-25"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Picasso-refQueue"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RxSchedulerPurge-1"
```

Comment: You may be loading large bitmaps in the app. You can try ```android:largeHeap="true"``` in ```Application``` tag In ```AndroidManifest.xml``` file.

Comment: This is true when we build the app in a device, not in the case of executing unit tests in the pipeline

Comment: What tasks are you using to build and test your Android app in Azure Pipelines? Share the YAML definition with the details.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT The question I have posted is for Azure pipeline only, I think ChiragThummar was explaining it in terms of GitHub Actions.

Comment: @Maddy, as mentioned previously, share the YAML of your azure pipeline used to build and test your Android app.